# Linux epoch time

Tags: linux, time

In Linux, is there an easy way to set the epoch time value directly??  I know there's a bunch of ways to format the date command, but none of them appears to fit our needs.

What we're doing is using an Android phone to set the time on an embedded Linux device when it connects.  Getting the epoch time on the Android is a no brainer, but all attempts to get this information accepted by the Linux device have been rebuffed.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you're trying to do, but the time of the epoch is fixed at midnight January 1st 1970 and I seriously doubt you can change that...

Comment: Don't want to change that.  I want to set the time on one machine using the epoch time provided by another.  Converting the epoch time to some human-readable format, just to use it in the Linux "date" command -- which will convert the human-readable format back to epoch time -- doesn't seem to make sense.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't have a machine I can run it on right now, but does:

```
date -s @1190000000
```

work for you?  (Obviously change the timestamp)

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thanks for the info.  Did you know this literally doesn't appear in any man page anywhere?  (As far as we were able to determine...)

Comment: The man pages are no longer the primary documentation for the GNU core utilities.  See: http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Seconds-since-the-Epoch.html